# Azure Availability Set : Servers Sync

Tags: azure

I am sorry if my question is very general - I just started with azure...

We are working with Azure and we currently have only one `VM`.
I would like to add a second `VM` and to place them both under the same `availability set`. The thing is that using our APP our users are posting files to the server and then a third party (`twilio`) should read the files. I need the two servers to be sync immediately to make sure the files are exists in both server.

Is it possible? 
I be happy to get the outlines of how this should be done.

Answer (score 1):

You can use azure files and attach it to both machines and store your files over there

Answer (score 1):

Availability sets have nothing to do with VM syncing; it's about ensuring your VMs aren't upgraded at the same time or placed all in the same physical location.

You'll need to store your uploaded outside of your VMs in a common area (whether in blobs, or an Azure File share, or even in a database). Otherwise, you'll need to create your own way of syncing (copying) content between your VMs.

There's no right way to store your data, and the options I listed each have their pros and cons. You'll need to choose what's right for your app.